# HTML file changes not reflecting in the browser in Magento

Tags: magento2

I would like to edit vendor\magento\module-payment\view\frontend\web\template\payment\cc-form.html and related JS files from where **cc-form.html** is calling.

My changes not reflecting on browser when I edit **cc-form.html** file.

It's working fine in localhost and also changes reflcting. Just have an issue with my online store. Also need help to find the JS from where **cc-form.html** is calling.

I already tried these things:

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- rm -rf var/cache/*
- rm -rf var/page_cache/*
- rm -rf var/generation/*
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- Clearing browser cache. etc

Answer (score 4):

you need to cleat the static content that is into **pub/static** folder

for this run following command

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs/
```

than after you need to deploy the files using following command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

now your updated files are deployed into **pub/static** folder.

now clean cache and try Browsing your website

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to just clean the cache using the below command:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```